# npm run build fails if react-bootstrap-table is enabled in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

In my component I have this : `import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';`

Then I run `npm run build` >> FAIL (check the screenshot)

If I comment or remove this line //import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';

Then I run `npm run build` >> OK, no errors.

Why? And how to solve that? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us your code in your bundle.js at the line 58577:15.

Comment: Tried a fresh install of node_modules?